# MS Access Data Entry Validation

Tags: ms-access

I've been tasked with creating a database to help with my company's annual physical inventory count. We have an ERP system that contains all our part numbers, and all of our part numbers come in boxes that have a carton label containing "part number" and "quantity" which are both barcoded. We are trying to switch to a system in which we scan all the boxes into my access database vs. our previous system of physically counting and writing tags. So far everything works great, the only issue is that some bar codes get damaged or just won't scan properly for some reason, so the scanners read the barcode as a part number that doesn't exist. We are able to export a list of all part numbers from our ERP system into an excel file which i have linked to my database that we use to see which part numbers were entered that don't exist in the system. My question is, is there a way to prevent people from scanning part numbers that don't match any part number in the excel file exported from our ERP system? I'm using ms access 2003

Comment: Yes. Look up the scanned part number in the linked table. If no match, enter the part number manually.

Comment: Use a combobox with LimitToList property set to yes.

Comment: @June7 you pretty much nailed it man. I was thinking that I would have to do some crazy  validation rule expression, I can't believe it was this simple all along. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using a combobox with LimitToList property set to yes is a great solution. Just to let you know that with this solution it is still possible to PASTE values that are NOT on the list. If you want to guarantee that it is not possible that the field contains wrong values, the best is that you create a Relationship (with referential integrity) taking the Table field containing all valid part numbers as the master field, and the one taking the scanned value as the slave field.

Comment: I tested pasting an invalid value and I still get a warning that the item is not in list when trying to exit combobox. If you mean pasting value could occur directly in table, yes that is possible. Users should not be working directly with tables or queries. However, setting a Relationship wouldn't hurt and set Enforce Referential Integrity to yes.

Comment: Good comment. I have modified my answer to include explicitly that the relationship should have referential integrity. Regarding pasting values  not in the list, you can paste them (as a whole cell, not as text) if the Record source of the ComboBox is an explicit list of values. You can also enter values not in the list in case you use INSERT or UPDATE. No intention to contradict, just to clarify.